# How to configure a retry policy while triggering only one message error - MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm developing a .NET application that uses MassTransit to handle exceptions by sending logs to RabbitMQ.

The framework allows to configure a retry policy that I've programmed successfully. However, when an error occurs, the program sends the message to the _error queue on RabbitMQ before retrying the process. When the retry attempts end, another message is sent to the _error queue.

```
configuration.ReceiveEndpoint("idfmdocument", e =>
                    {
                        e.UseMessageRetry(retry => retry.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
                        e.UseInMemoryOutbox();
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<IDFMDocumentConsumer>(context);
                    });
```

I was wondering if there is a way to handle this by only sending one error message to RabbitMQ.

Comment: That isn't normal behavior, you have something else wrong in your configuration. I would suggest reviewing the logs generated by MassTransit to identify the root cause.